# Frozen time equilibria are not solutions of nonautonomous system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am reading the following textbook:

`Introduction to Applied Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Chaos` by Wiggins 
p.6 (top)

Suppose we have $$\dot{x} = f(x,t), \ \ \ x\in \mathbb{R}^n $$

By implicit function theorem, if we can find $(\bar{x},\bar{t})$ such that $f(\bar{x},\bar{t})=0$ and $D_xf(\bar{x},\bar{t})\neq 0$, then we can find $\bar{x}(t)$, with $\bar{x}(\bar{t})=\bar{x}$ such that $f(\bar{x}(t),t)=0$.

> If $\bar{x}(t)$ is a solution of the nonautonomous vector field, then it must be constant in time, i.e., $\dot{\bar{x}}(t)=0$.

Why this is the case? I am confused about it.

Comment: The implicit function theorem guarantees the existence of a $C^1$ function $\bar{x}\colon(\bar{t}-\epsilon,\bar{t}+\epsilon)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(\bar{x}(t),t)=0$ for all $t\in(\bar{t}-\epsilon,\bar{t}+\epsilon)$. But that $\bar{x}$ being a solution means that $\dot{\bar{x}}(t)=f(\bar{x}(t),t)$, which is equal to $0$ by the above reasoning. Consequently, $\bar{x}$ must be constant, at least on $(\bar{t}-\epsilon,\bar{t}+\epsilon)$.

Comment: @user539887 Thanks! I get it.